# Upper Bounds on Derivative

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Given an N-times differentiable function s(x), what are some tools or refences that present a study of inequality of the form,

${\left| {{s^{\left( m \right)}}\left( x \right)} \right|_\infty } \leqslant {C_m}{\left| {s\left( x \right)} \right|_\infty }$

where ${{s^{\left( m \right)}}\left( x \right)}$ is the m'th derivative of s(x), $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and ${\left| {s\left( x \right)} \right|_\infty }$ is the max-norm.

For instance, when $s(x)$ is compactly supported in the Fourier domain, that is, $s\left( x \right) = \int_{\left| z \right| \leqslant {z_0}} {{e^{jzt}}\widehat s\left( z \right)dz}$, one has, ${C_m} = z_0^m$. A similar form exists for polynomials. I am keen on finding references so that other techniques and methods for more general form of $s(x)$ can be investigated.

Answer (score 2):

These inequalities are useful in harmonic analysis. For instance, Mihilin’s multiplier theorem deals with operators whose symbols satisfy such hypothesis. See here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)

Don’t know any particular reference, but I think any book about harmonic analysis study them.

The only request about $s$ I can remember is about the support of its Fourier transform. Inequalities like these should be called “Bernstein inequalities”, see for instance one of the first results here for a proof and a precise statement:

https://perso.math.u-pem.fr/danchin.raphael/cours/courschine.pdf

I followed a course where such spaces were called $\mathcal{S}^k$, but I don’t know if it’s a widespread notation